# using HTTPRequest setPayload in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, http-post, httprequest, urlfetch

I am trying to do HTTPRequest Post via Google App Engine.
This is what I have so far

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com/myfile.php");
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);
request.setPayload(########);
HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);
```

Here I need to put some paired values (ie. "email","hi@example.com" etc)
Since setPayload accept byte[] I have no idea how to convert my paired values 
into byte.

I have searched other posts but I am very stuck.

EDIT:
I have changed to this but it is still not working

```
byte[] data = ("EMAIL=bo0@gmail.com&amp;TITLE=evolution&amp;COMMENT=comments&amp;PRICE=5000;").getBytes();
try {
URL url = new URL("http://www.bo.x10.mx/nPost.php");
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);
request.setPayload(data);
HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);
```

This is what I have on php website.

```
<?php
include "path/conf.php"; //logging into database works
$tb_name = 'Post';
$EMAIL=$_POST['EMAIL'];
$TITLE =$_POST['TITLE'];
$COMMENT =$_POST['COMMENT'];
$PRICE =$_POST['PRICE'];
if(!isset($EMAIL) || !isset($TITLE ) || !isset($PRICE )|| !isset($COMMENT)){
header('HTTP/1.0 412 Precondition Failed', true, 412);
die('Bad data');
}
$sql="INSERT INTO $tb_name(EMAIL, TITLE, COMMENT, PRICE) VALUES ('$EMAIL', '$TITLE ', '$COMMENT ', '$PRICE ')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result==TRUE){
echo "successfully inserted into table!";}
else{
echo "error in inserting into table!";
header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);}
ob_end_flush();
exit();
?>
```

EDIT2: This is a working code

```
try{
byte[] data = ("EMAIL=bo0@gmail.com&TITLE=evolution&COMMENT=comments&PRICE=5000").getBytes("UTF-8");
URL url = new URL("http://www.box.com/nost.php");
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);
request.setPayload(data);
HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);
}
```

My database string field is of type UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a `String` with the request body, and then you get the byte array. For example we have:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com/myfile.php");
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);
String body = "email=" + email + "&mpla=" + mpla;
request.setPayload(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should also set a proper content type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thanos, I have tried and this does not seem to work. This is currently what I have.

    byte[] data = ("EMAIL=bo90@gmail.com&amp;TITLE=evolution&amp;COMMENT=comments&amp;PRICE=5000;").getBytes();
    URL url = new URL("www.somewbesite/myPHPFILE.php");
    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);
    request.setPayload(data);
    HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);
on php site
    $EMAIL=$_POST['EMAIL'];
    $TITLE =$_POST['TITLE'];
    $COMMENT =$_POST['COMMENT'];
    $PRICE =$_POST['PRICE'];

Comment: Not really an error, it seems to be doing http post without setting any of those field's values. I will edit my post so I can put all my codes

Comment: Hi Thanos, I just found out all the values got put into the Email field,(ie. "bo0@gmail.com;TITLE=evolution;COMMENT=comments;PRICE=5000;" )and rest of the field is empty.

Comment: Hmmm, try to replace `&amp;` with `&`.

Comment: oh Thanks Thanos it works perfectly!
I also changed the method from .getBytes() to .getBytes("UTF-8")